# Toggle filter show/hide searchandfilter shortcode Wordpress plugin not working well

Tags: wordpress, filter, toggle, show-hide

https://dev.annacdesign.com/resources/
here I've a searchandfilter shortcode that is visible when you press the filter button.

Problems:

1. when i start filtering and then i want to hide the shortcode/filters - the filter button is not responsive anymore, cant press it
2. the button's backgroung imagage should change, depending on the toggle state but it doesnt. Url's are fine.

```
javascript is in my functions.php:

function wpb_hook_javascript() {
    ?>
        <script>
          
          jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#toggle-button').click(function() {
    var filter = $('#filter');
    if (filter.is(':visible')) {
      filter.hide();
      $('#toggle-button i').removeClass('customise-icon').addClass('close-icon');
    } else {
      filter.show();
      $('#toggle-button i').removeClass('lose-icon').addClass('customise-icon');
    }
  });
});


        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'wpb_hook_javascript');


css:
#filter-icon {
  background-image: url('wp-content/themes/climate-communications/images/customise.svg'); /* Initial icon */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 24px; /* Adjust as needed */
  height: 24px; /* Adjust as needed */
  display: inline-block;
}

.customise-icon {
  background-image: url('wp-content/themes/climate-communications/images/customise.svg');
}

.close-icon {
  background-image: url('wp-content/themes/climate-communications/images/close.svg');
}

html:
<button class="btn_filter" id="toggle-button"><span class="customise-icon"></span></button>
<div id="filter" style="display: none;"><?php echo do_shortcode ('[searchandfilter id="4473"]'); ?></div>
```